# I cannot add "\s" regex in my HTML code

Tags: regex, html, wordpress

I am trying to allow a space in an input form field using HTML5 
the code:

```
<input id="insightly_FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text"  placeholder="characters and space only" pattern="^[A-Za-z.'-s]$" title="only Characters, spaces, and . ' - can be used" required/>
```

whenever I add \s and save the code Wordpress erases the "\s" sign!!

Comment: Can you share some code? It's pretty hard to make sense of this question without some more details

Comment: <input id="insightly_FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text"  placeholder="characters and space only" pattern="^[A-Za-z.'-s]$" title="only Characters, spaces, and . ' - can be used" required/>

Comment: Try double escaping it.

Comment: In `pattern` attribute you do not need the `^` and `$` anchors. They are implicit.

Comment: I hope you still check this in server side language?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution by adding a space inside the pattern like this :`"^[A-Za-z.'- ]$"`

Comment: You need to put the `-` at start or end of the character class: `[-A-Za-z. ']` else it indicates a range. If you want to check for one or more, use `+` [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html): `[-A-Za-z. ']+`